# Cannot access Kubernetes service

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

We are not able to access the nginx from outside the pod cluster. Kindly help us understand if below seems right and which port will be serving nginx. Running a curl on NodeIP:NodePort throws our company proxy access denied page. We have VM on openstack and Security Group is open.

`[root@ip-10-0-0-3 pods]# kubectl get deployments
NAME         DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
nginx-demo   2         2         2            2           4m`

`[root@ip-10-0-0-3 pods]# kubectl get pods
NAME                          READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-demo-1947000120-6omcz   1/1       Running   0          5m
nginx-demo-1947000120-exewa   1/1       Running   0          5m`

Below is the Kubernetes Deployment and service file.

`apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-demo
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-demo
  minReadySeconds: 20
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-demo
        version: v0.1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nginx-demo
          image: nginx
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: DEMO_ENV
              value: staging
**---**(ignore stars)
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginx-demo
  name: nginx-demo-svc
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      name: www
      nodePort: 30089
  selector:
    app: nginx-demo
  type: NodePort`

---

`[root@ip-10-0-0-3 pods]# kubectl describe svc
Name:                   nginx-demo-svc
Namespace:              default
Labels:                 app=nginx-demo
Selector:               app=nginx-demo
Type:                   NodePort
IP:                     192.168.1.20
Port:                   www     80/TCP
NodePort:               www     30089/TCP
Endpoints:              172.17.50.2:80,172.17.67.2:80
Session Affinity:       None
No events.`

---

`[root@ip-10-0-0-3 pods]# kubectl get svc
NAME             CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes       10.254.0.1     <none>        443/TCP   2d
nginx-demo-svc   192.168.1.20   <nodes>       80/TCP    9m`

---

Comment: Can you paste the output of your ``curl -v`` command as well (note the -``v``)?

Answer (score 0):

The selector section of your service must contains all labels :

```
selector:
  app: nginx-demo
  version: v0.1
```

It's better?